# How do I find numberOfRowsInSection for dataset of objects

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Below is a code and towards end, I am trying to figure out the method to count the number of rows in section

The NS Object Definition
    //DataDefinition.h
    #import

```
@interface DataDefinition : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *dataHeader;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *dataDetails;

@end
```

The Display header section
    //DataDisplay.h
    #import

```
#import "DataDefinition.h"

@interface DataDisplay : UITableViewController
@property (read write) NSInteger RowsCount;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *dataSet;
@property (strong, atomic) DataDefinition *individualData;

@end
```

The Display implementation section

```
//DataDisplay.m

 @interface DataDisplay ()
 @end

 @implementation DataDisplay
 @synthesize RowsCount;
 @synthesize dataSet;
 @synthesize individualData;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    individualData.dataHeader  = @"Header1";
    individualData.dataDetails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Header1-Detail1", @"Header1-Detail2", @"Header1-Detail3", nil];
    RowsCount = [individualData.dataDetails count];
    [dataSet addObject:individualData];
    .
    .
    . 
    [dataSet addObject:individualData];   

    self.title = @"DataDisplay";
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [dataSet count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in sections.
    return ?????
}
```

Comment: Read the FAQ:http://stackoverflow.com/faq and either accept my answer or write ur own answer and accept it so that people will know the question has been answered...

Comment: I am new to this place and would love to accept your answer. But it needs to be corrected the way Darren has written. And by the way, how do I accept your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First if you don't have section in the dataset you want to display you don't have to implement this method. You need otherwise to store your data in an NSMutableArray which will be an array of array: this will basically store your content per section.

You can then imagine access to your number of items per section this way:

> [[self.yourarray objectAtIndex:section] count];

**EDIT**

According to your source code and from the discussion we have your code should be:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in sections.
    return [((DataDefinition*)[self.dataSet objectAtIndex:section]).dataDetails count] 
}
```

Comment: Won't that always give me just 1. I want the method to access datadetails count

Comment: No for e.g [self.dataSet objectAtIndex:0] will return the array of your first section so [[self.dataSet objectAtIndex:0] count] will return your number of rows for your first section so 2

Comment: I have now added for first section data details 3 data constants. "Header1-Detail1", @"Header1-Detail2", @"Header1-Detail3" I need the count 3 for section 0. So [self.dataSet objectAtIndex:0] will return the array of first section as you say. Now what will [[self.dataSet objectAtIndex:0] count] give me. Will it be 3. I guess not. Let me try and get back

Comment: [self.dataSet objectAtIndex:0] is not going to return an array. It's going to return a DataDefinition object. You need to use [((DataDefinition*)[self.dataSet objectAtIndex:0]).dataDetails count]

Comment: Darren is right. Atleast I dont have errors. To get this working, I am trying to figure out how to display cell.textLabel.text